# How to insert into postgres jsonb column

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert

Got a column that I contains an empty dictionary

I want to insert other objects into it such that after I insert others, the data column (JSONField) will look like

```
{
 "2021-08-10":{...}, 
 "2021-08-11":{...}
}
```

Easily doable in Django with `dict_["key"]=obj`, but I'm trying to avoid to pull the object into memory, so how can achieve this in postgres? Any takers?